# How to fill dataframe's empty/nan cell with conditional column mean

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to fill the (pandas) dataframe's null/empty value using the mean of that specific column.

The data looks like this:

```
    ID  Name        Industry            Year        Revenue
    1   Treslam     Financial Services  2009        $5,387,469 
    2   Rednimdox   Construction        2013    
    3   Lamtone     IT Services         2009        $11,757,018 
    4   Stripfind   Financial Services  2010        $12,329,371 
    5   Openjocon   Construction        2013        $4,273,207 
    6   Villadox    Construction        2012        $1,097,353 
    7   Sumzoomit   Construction        2010        $7,703,652
    8   Abcddd      Construction        2019    
    .
    .
```

I am trying to fill that empty cell with the mean of Revenue column where Industry is == 'Construction'.

To get our numerical mean value I did:

```
df.groupby(['Industry'], as_index = False).mean()
```

I am trying to do something like this to fill up that empty cell in-place:

```
(df[df['Industry'] == "Construction"]['Revenue']).fillna("$21212121.01", inplace = True)
```

..but it is not working. Can anyone tell me how to achieve it! Thanks a lot.

Expected Output:

```
ID  Name        Industry            Year        Revenue
1   Treslam     Financial Services  2009        $5,387,469 
2   Rednimdox   Construction        2013        $21212121.01
3   Lamtone     IT Services         2009        $11,757,018 
4   Stripfind   Financial Services  2010        $12,329,371 
5   Openjocon   Construction        2013        $4,273,207 
6   Villadox    Construction        2012        $1,097,353 
7   Sumzoomit   Construction        2010        $7,703,652
8   Abcddd      Construction        2019        $21212121.01
.
.
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Also, what is the purpose of the string "numerical_MeanValue"? IS that literally what you want to fill with? Or, is that a placeholder and you really want to calculate the mean?

Comment: @DavidErickson: i updated the issue. Thanks for pointing that out. The mean() code that i used above will give us a table per Industry type. So i looked at the mean, which was 21212121.01 . This is am trying to use in the final command. Mayb there is more concise way of doing all this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the numbers used as averages are different, we have presented two types of averages: the normal average and the average calculated on the number of cases that include NaN.

```
df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].replace({'\$':'', ',':''}, regex=True)
df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].astype(float)
df_mean = df.groupby(['Industry'], as_index = False)['Revenue'].mean()

df_mean
    Industry    Revenue
0   Construction    4.358071e+06
1   Financial Services  8.858420e+06
2   IT Services 1.175702e+07

df_mean_nan = df.groupby(['Industry'], as_index = False)['Revenue'].agg({'Sum':np.sum, 'Size':np.size})
df_mean_nan['Mean_nan'] = df_mean_nan['Sum'] / df_mean_nan['Size']

df_mean_nan

    Industry    Sum Size    Mean_nan
0   Construction    13074212.0  5.0 2614842.4
1   Financial Services  17716840.0  2.0 8858420.0
2   IT Services 11757018.0  1.0 11757018.0
```

Average taking into account the number of NaNs

```
df.loc[df['Revenue'].isna(),['Revenue']] = df_mean_nan.loc[df_mean_nan['Industry'] == 'Construction',['Mean_nan']].values

df
    ID  Name    Industry    Year    Revenue
0   1   Treslam Financial Services  2009    5387469.0
1   2   Rednimdox   Construction    2013    2614842.4
2   3   Lamtone IT Services 2009    11757018.0
3   4   Stripfind   Financial Services  2010    12329371.0
4   5   Openjocon   Construction    2013    4273207.0
5   6   Villadox    Construction    2012    1097353.0
6   7   Sumzoomit   Construction    2010    7703652.0
7   8   Abcddd  Construction    2019    2614842.4
```

Normal average: (NaN is excluded)

```
df.loc[df['Revenue'].isna(),['Revenue']] = df_mean.loc[df_mean['Industry'] == 'Construction',['Revenue']].values

df
    ID  Name    Industry    Year    Revenue
0   1   Treslam Financial Services  2009    5.387469e+06
1   2   Rednimdox   Construction    2013    4.358071e+06
2   3   Lamtone IT Services 2009    1.175702e+07
3   4   Stripfind   Financial Services  2010    1.232937e+07
4   5   Openjocon   Construction    2013    4.273207e+06
5   6   Villadox    Construction    2012    1.097353e+06
6   7   Sumzoomit   Construction    2010    7.703652e+06
7   8   Abcddd  Construction    2019    4.358071e+06
```

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners. Clean , awesome.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you too. Was the intent of the question requiring an average including NaN?

Comment: I think the excluding nan should be better for the excel data that i am importing as dataframe which has some of its cells/columns empty.

Comment: I just noticed, if 'Financial Services' Revenue is also nan, this will insert the mean value to those also. How can we make it specific to 'Construction' types only!? Thanks

Comment: The extraction method remains the same. `df_mean.loc[df_mean['Industry']] == 'Financial Services
',['Revenue']].values`