# Fill nan's in dataframe after filtering column by names

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

Can anyone please tell me what the right approach here to filter (and fill nan) based on another column name. *Thanks a lot.*

Related link: [How to fill dataframe's empty/nan cell with conditional column mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023890/how-to-fill-dataframes-empty-nan-cell-with-conditional-column-mean)

```
df

ID  Name        Industry            Expenses
1   Treslam     Financial Services  734545
2   Rednimdox   Construction        nan
3   Lamtone     IT Services         567678
4   Stripfind   Financial Services  nan
5   Openjocon   Construction        8678957
6   Villadox    Construction        5675676
7   Sumzoomit   Construction        231244
8   Abcd        Construction        nan
9   Stripfind   Financial Services  nan


df_mean_expenses = (df.groupby(['Industry'], as_index = False)['Expenses']).mean()
df_mean_expenses

  Industry           Expenses
0 Construction       554433.11
1 Financial Services 2362818.48
2 IT Services        149153.46
```

*In order to* replace the Contruction-Revenue nan's by the contruction row's mean (in df_mean_expenses) , i tried two approaches:

1.
df.loc[df['Expenses'].isna(),['Expenses']][df['Industry'] == 'Construction'] = df_mean_expenses.loc[df_mean_expenses['Industry'] == 'Construction',['Expenses']].values

.. returns Error: Item wrong length 500 instead of 3!

2.

df['Expenses'][np.isnan(df['Expenses'])][df['Industry'] == 'Construction'] = df_mean_expenses.loc[df_mean_expenses['Industry'] == 'Construction',['Expenses']].values
.. this runs but does not add values to the df.

Expected output:

```
df

 ID Name        Industry            Expenses
    1   Treslam     Financial Services  734545
    2   Rednimdox   Construction        554433.11
    3   Lamtone     IT Services         567678
    4   Stripfind   Financial Services  nan
    5   Openjocon   Construction        8678957
    6   Villadox    Construction        5675676
    7   Sumzoomit   Construction        231244
    8   Abcd        Construction        554433.11
    9   Stripfind   Financial Services  nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `transform`

```
df_mean_expenses = df.groupby('Industry')['Expenses'].transform('mean')
df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].fillna(df_mean_expenses[df['Industry']=='Construction'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works, but it also fills Financial Services nan cell. I only want to fill Construction industry types.

Comment: @Joe check the update `df_mean_expenses[df['Industry']=='Construction']`

Comment: That helped. Thanks a lot.